# virtual memory optimization on exchange server 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, optimization, performance-tuning, virtual-memory

Hi I did some Google searching but came up blank

I know mycomputer/computer > Properties > advance System settings > Advance[tab] > Settings[Performance] > Advance [Tab] > Change > customsige

Initial size = the entier amoung [ex - 12GB]

Max size     = 12GBx3[36GB]+300mb

Will it help exchange server in any way? As far as performing and taking up 98% of the physical memeory

Comment: This answers my question I was thinking even after adding additional ram 32gb total exchange still is using 98%

Comment: I'll write this up as a proper answer, so you can select it and close out the question if that's ok with you

Answer (score 2):

Exchange will use all the memory it can find, so if you're worried that its using most of your server ram then don't be - it's working as intended. If it's dipping heavily into the pagefile then your best bet is to buy more RAM for the server or reduce its workload. Altering the pagefile settings aren't likely to help you much - the database takes a big performance hit from having to go out to disk too often.

If you add more RAM then exchange will use all of that too, if it has a need to. It's essentially a database server, and like most database servers it will use as much RAM as it can lay its hands on because the more of the database that is cached in RAM, the faster it will perform. This is a *good thing* if the system is a dedicated exchange server.

If you have a need to limit the RAM used then this is possible too, but I suggest you avoid this if possible:

To limit the amount of memory that Exchange uses, do the following ([source](http://ct-miramar.com/blog/2011/08/02/limit-the-amount-of-memory-that-exchange-2010-uses/)):

> 1. Start ADSIEDIT.msc
> 2. Right click on ADSI Edit and click Connect to…
> 3. Under Select a well know Naming Context, select Configuration
> 4. Navigate to Configuration\Services\Microsoft Exchange\\Administrative Groups\<”Exchange
>      Administrative Group”\Servers\\InformationStore
> 5. Right-click InformationStore,
> 6. Edit msExchESEParamCacheSizeMax
> 7. Set it it to the number of pages to maximize the Database Cache to. Note that Exchange 2007 works with 8 KB pages and Exchange 2010 with 32 KB pages!
>
> Restart the Microsoft Exchange Information Store service for the
>   change to become effective.
>
> NOTE: For instance, if you want to limit the Database Cache to 4 GB of
>   an Exchange 2010 server, set msExchESEparamCacheSizeMax to 131072 (4
>   GB = 4.194.304 KB / 32 KB). That’s equal to 1,048,576 for each
>   gigabyte of memory. 1,048,576 * 4 = 4,194,304.
>
> To configure 5GB of memory, (1,048,576 * 5 = 5,242,880 / 32 = 163840)
>   . msExchESEparamCacheSizeMax to 163840

Answer (score 0):

You don't ever want the system using the pagefile.  So leaving it at defaults is usually fine.

Exchange will manage to use up almost all of your ram.  It does this on purpose.  The more data it keeps in (very fast) ram the less it needs to use (relatively slow) hard drives.  Unused ram is wasted ram so using as much as possible is the best use of resources.  It will free some of it up if other programs require it.

If you are consistently using a lot of pagefile you need more ram.  Simple as that :)